# What are "spectral characteristics" in random number engines?

Tags: c++

On http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random:

> The Mersenne twister is slower and has greater state storage
>   requirements but with the right parameters has the longest
>   non-repeating sequence with the most desirable spectral
>   characteristics (for a given definition of desirable).

What do they mean by spectral characteristics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained by Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test

> The spectral test is a statistical test for the quality of a class of pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs), the linear congruential generators (LCGs).[1] LCGs have a property that when plotted in 2 or more dimensions, lines or hyperplanes will form, on which all possible outputs can be found.

So presumably "desirable spectral characteristics" means that a given PRNG is harder to predict through spectral-analysis.